# over lapping 1 div but is does not distort the site or dis arrange the site

Tags: html, css, position, positioning, overlap

I been trying to search what is the cost of this problem. my div 
if you could is the red background. it overlap to the top of nav and other div.
I thought the problem is my div or grouping of my div, I thought may i forgot to close one of the div. I double check each div but sadly i did not fine any error. I know that there is error because it overlap but i cannot fine it.

if hope anyone get my point and my problem. its been more than a month now. I my a beginner in html and css

thank you so much

```css
.content{
 width:1024px;
 margin:auto;
 height: 2000px;
 color: ffffff;
 background-color: #17120f;
}


.bigimage{
 heigth: 100px; 
 background-color: red;
}
 
.signage{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.navicon{
 float:left;
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 940px;
}


.signage{
 float: left;
 width:  65%;
 

}
.nav{
 float: left;
 width: 35%; 
 margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.nav li{
 display: inline;

}

.nav ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: ffffff;
}

.bigimage{
 
 margin-left: 5px;

}

.treeparagh{
 margin-top: 20px;

}


.firstparag{
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 9px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 background-color: #17120f;
}





.firstimage{
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-right:10px; 

}



.secondparag{
 float: left;
 width: 30%; 
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 9px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 background-color: #17120f;
}



.secondimage{
 float: left;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}


.thirdparag{
 float: left;
 width: 30%;  
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 background-color: #17120f;
 
}


.thirdimage{
 float: left;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}


.firsttwoparagh{
 width: 60%;
 float: left;

}

.treeparagh{
 background-color:red;

}
```

```html
<body>

 <div class = "content">
  
        <div class = "navicon">

     <a href="#"><img src ="D:\1 DREAM\PROJECT 2\IMGS/house icon.png"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src ="D:\1 DREAM\PROJECT 2\IMGS/mail icon.png"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src ="D:\1 DREAM\PROJECT 2\IMGS/stracture icon.png"/></a>
  
  </div>   

  <div class ="secondpart">

   
   <div class = "signage">

     <a href="#"><img src ="D:\1 DREAM\PROJECT 2\IMGS/topimages.png"/></a>

   </div>

   <div class = "nav">

    <ul>
                 
                     <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> Service</a> </li>
                     <li><a href="#"> Porfolio</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> About</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Contact Us</a> </li>
                             
             
             </ul>

   </div>      

   

  </div>     

  
   <div class = "bigimage">

   <a href="#"><img src ="D:\1 DREAM\PROJECT 2\IMGS/center image.png"/></a>

   </div>  

  
   <div class = "treeparagh">

   <div class = "firstparag">


    <div class = "firstimage">
    
     <a href="#"><img src ="D:\1 DREAM\PROJECT 2\IMGS/firstparagh.png"/></a>

    </div>


    <div class = "firsttitle">

     <h1>FIRST PARAGPAH </h1>

    </div> 

    <div class ="firstbody">

     <p >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy                             text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has                        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,It was popularised in the 1960s with the                        release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus                        PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                 <a href="#"> Read More </a>   

    </div>

   </div>  


   <div class = "secondparag">

    
    <div class = "secondimage">

     <a href="#"><img src ="D:\1 DREAM\PROJECT 2\IMGS/secondparagh.png"/></a>

    </div>


    <div class = "secondtitle">

     <h1>SECOND PARAGHAP</h1>

    </div>


    <div class = "secondbody">

     <p >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy                        text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has                        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,It was popularised in the 1960s with the                        release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus                        PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                 <a href="#"> Read More </a>   

    </div>

   </div>     

   <div class = "thirdparag">
   
   

    <div class = "thirdimage">

     <a href="#"><img src ="D:\1 DREAM\PROJECT 2\IMGS/thirdparagh.png"/></a>
    
    </div>


    <div class = "thirdtitle">

     <h1> THIS IS IT </h1>
    
    </div>

    <div class = "thirdbody">

     <p >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy                       text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has                       survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,It was popularised in the 1960s with the                       release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus                       PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                 <a href="#"> Read More </a>   
 
    </div>


   </div>        
   
  
        </div>



  </div>   
 
            
         
            
          

</div>
 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra div closing at the bottom
go check your html https://validator.w3.org/

```html
</div>
```